# Algorithms question: Largest contiguous subarray selection

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Q. Given two arrays, A and B, of equal length, find the largest possible contiguous subarray of indices [i,j] such that max(A[i: j]) < min(B[i: j]).

Example: A = [10, 21, 5, 1, 3], B = [3, 1, 4, 23, 56]

Explanation: A[4] = 1, A[5] = 3, B[4] = 23, B[5] = 56, max(A[4], A[5]) < min(B[4], B[5])

The indices are [4,5] (inclusive), and the largest contiguous subarray has length 2

I can do this in O(n2) brute force method but cannot seem to reduce the time complexity. Any ideas?

Comment: What is B[i,j] ...?

Comment: B[i,j] contains all the elements from index i to index j from the array B

Comment: It is not formalized correctly. The constraint you've mentioned is `max(A[i, j]) < B[i, j]`, but `B[i, j]` is a subarray of ints, so what exactly did you mean? It is that `max(A[i, j])` should be smaller than **any** of the elements in `B[i, j]`?

Comment: Yeah, but in the same range of indexes in B

Comment: Thanks, mistakenly forgot to add the main point

Comment: So how _a single value_ `max(A[i,j])` chosen from `A` gets compared to a _set of values_ taken from `B`?

Comment: It's in the description, guys: *"max(A[4], A[5]) < min(B[4], B[5])"*

Comment: A[i,j] = A[i : j] (like in python syntax but j th element is inclusive). It contains all the elements from the i th element to the jth element

Comment: @CiaPan Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is this from? Can solutions be tested online somewhere?

Comment: What did you try so far? I think we can achieve O(n) by using approach similar to KMP algorithm, which can result O(n) complexity.

Comment: The question is from an archived material of an Algorithms course. Since it is a theoretical course, there are no test cases to be tested for correctness

Comment: @Thinhbk can you explain your approach? I can't see how you are relating to KMP. Also the length of the arrays are same as mentioned in the question

Comment: I think the key approach is to have 2 for loop for matching/ validating, but the outer loop does not have to jump back once finding a violation to the condition from the inner loop, which resulting O(n) complexity instead of O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: Want to keep it free from any language and codes, as it is a theoretical question

Comment: One idea that comes to mind is using mono queues prefix and suffix for max of A and min of B. I think there may be a linear solution from there but I'm not sure of it.

Comment: Does `divide-and-conquer` tag refers to corresponding chapter of algorithms course?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O(n) solution:

Move index `j` from left to right and drag `i` behind so that the window from `i` to `j` is valid. So always increase `j` by 1, and then increase `i` as much as needed for the window to be valid.

To do that, keep a queue `Aq` of indexes of non-increasing A-values. Then `A[Aq[0]]` tells you the max A-value in the window. Similarly, keep a queue for non-decreasing B-values.

For each new `j`, first update `Aq` and `Bq` according to the new A-value and new B-value. Then, while the window is invalid, increase `i` and drop `Aq[0]` and `Bq[0]` if they're `i`. When both `j` and `i` are updated, update the result with the window size `j - i - 1`.

Python implementation:

```
def solution(A, B):
    Aq = deque()
    Bq = deque()
    i = 0
    maxlen = 0
    for j in range(len(A)):
        while Aq and A[Aq[-1]] < A[j]:
            Aq.pop()
        Aq.append(j)
        while Bq and B[Bq[-1]] > B[j]:
            Bq.pop()
        Bq.append(j)
        while Aq and A[Aq[0]] >= B[Bq[0]]:
            if Aq[0] == i:
                Aq.popleft()
            if Bq[0] == i:
                Bq.popleft()
            i += 1
        maxlen = max(maxlen, j - i + 1)
    return maxlen
```

Test results from comparing against a naive brute force reference solution:

```
expect:  83   result:  83   same: True
expect: 147   result: 147   same: True
expect: 105   result: 105   same: True
expect:  71   result:  71   same: True
expect: 110   result: 110   same: True
expect:  56   result:  56   same: True
expect: 140   result: 140   same: True
expect: 109   result: 109   same: True
expect:  86   result:  86   same: True
expect: 166   result: 166   same: True
```

Testing code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPRbqMwEHznK/attkorSHrSKSqV8G9E0YkjptkUbMc4d62qfntujV1CiHK8sLuzMx57bfPhdlotfxp7OjVWd@Cwk@gAO6Oti1kyILZSW/pFpN5prGUfoFq3rawdatV/41t5OMqAopPWad2OWK2736iqoT9JtrKBXrdHn7IyBcFXCdBXHqAIMowPBTEvIOXZEHXVeyvVmDbawh5Qec@vkhHESh5l/fd3h630C9CWoFyXh/VDvtnAM8X7zbktuHg02sQFY6EyRqot2/OZoAiCYi2i4AvFc0ExFxS3BacOM69XBHGKL0WxgaEFigLwEjpvopWNm6wbeeI/PHGTB/cF5GNpPH4KWEhSGsCD74M8UK10R6tia5i6qvCPnI783MPYSL9y5aeLaRjw9Cqxi2mnsOBXVNqvFy/XuNrf5xtOI@9QMfGd83ROIZ/VsXVFxpPEL/zrfK3yLNr2O/@RhatXUhzfRvTztCAvb4WKl/gKzxfLp2mHfDf0lqhtcjzxdHpyQsDlaxkwY1E51twF8go@Y7D8GolUjMFQ7KtOjiU//8D4uuOn0z8))

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import choices
from collections import deque
from itertools import combinations

def solution(A, B):
    Aq = deque()
    Bq = deque()
    i = 0
    maxlen = 0
    for j in range(len(A)):
        while Aq and A[Aq[-1]] < A[j]:
            Aq.pop()
        Aq.append(j)
        while Bq and B[Bq[-1]] > B[j]:
            Bq.pop()
        Bq.append(j)
        while Aq and A[Aq[0]] >= B[Bq[0]]:
            if Aq[0] == i:
                Aq.popleft()
            if Bq[0] == i:
                Bq.popleft()
            i += 1
        maxlen = max(maxlen, j - i + 1)
    return maxlen

def naive(A, B):
    return max((j - i + 1
                for i, j in combinations(range(len(A)), 2)
                if max(A[i:j+1]) < min(B[i:j+1])),
               default=0)

for _ in range(10):
    n = 500
    A = choices(range(42), k=n)
    B = choices(range(1234), k=n)
    expect = naive(A, B)
    result = solution(A, B)
    print(f'expect: {expect:3}   result: {result:3}   same: {result == expect}')
```

Comment: Beat me a minute with same idea ;)  [longer code](https://ideone.com/M1brIL)

Comment: @MBo Great, now I *really* don't know what to do next. More properly test my code, read the answer that claims O(n) without extra data structures, or read yours :-)

Comment: No need to read mine - similar idea, worse implementation ;)

Comment: An awesome solution indeed. Thanks for helping me with the solution. Order of N solutions are really something!

Comment: Great solution. Can't do better myself. +1 for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I can see based on the problem, saying we have 2 conditions:

- max(A[i,j-1]) < min(B[i,j-1])
- max(A[i,j]) >= min(B[i,j])
- saying maxA is index of max item in A array in [i,j], minB is index of min item in B array in [i,j]; and anchor is min(maxA, minB)

Then we will have: max(A[i+k,anchor]) >= min(B[i+k,anchor]) ∀ k in [i+1,anchor].

So I come up with a  simple algorithm like below:

```
    int extractLongestRange(int n, int[] A, int[] B) {
        // n is size of both array
        int size = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int maxAIndex = i;
            int minBIndex = i;
            for(int j = i; j < n; j++){
                if(A[maxAIndex] < A[j]){
                    maxAIndex = j;
                }
                if(B[minBIndex] > B[j]){
                    minBIndex = j;
                }
                if(A[maxAIndex] >= B[minBIndex]){
                    if(size < j - i){
                        size = j - i;
                    }
                    // here, need to jump back to min of maxAIndex and minBIndex.
                    i = Math.min(maxAIndex, minBIndex);
                    break;
                }
                // this case, if j reach the end of array
                if(j == n - 1){
                    if(size < j - i + 1){
                        size = j - i + 1;
                        i = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return size; 
}
```

With this approach, the complexity is O(n).
We can change the output to pick-up the other information if needed.

Comment: This solution is also awesome and is the answer to the problem. Thanks for spending some time on this problem. It helped me greatly.

Comment: But, it is giving wrong answer for arr1[] = {1, 2, 25, 1, 100}, arr2[] = {3, 10, 4, 23, 56};. Answer = 2, answer this function gives: 3

Comment: Good catch, have to move break to outer if condition, once there're chances that the 2 last condition matches. Updated.

Comment: @Thinhbk Could you add a link to a full program for easier testing?

Comment: @Davidjones It's wrong, though. Already the "observation" is wrong.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: I am using java for my implementation, don't know how to add a link for it to be honest. I can convert my algorithm to javascript and put it to jsfiddle if you are interested.

Comment: @Thinhbk For example [like this](https://ideone.com/jXkh5B). Which contains an  example case that hopefully makes clear why your approach doesn't work: `A = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}` `B = {2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}`. You compute 5 instead of 8.

Comment: Hmm,I know the reason why my algo does not work with this input, I think i (the outer index) should jump back the the min of maxA index and minB index to be safe, that should work.

Comment: For `A = {2}` `B = {1}` your new code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in `O(n log(n))`.

Here is an outline of my technique.

My idea looks like a "rising water level" of maximum in A, keeping track of the "islands" emerging in `A`, and the "islands" submerging in `B`. And recording the maximum intersections after they appear from `A` emerging, or before they disappear from `B` sinking.

We will need 2 balanced binary trees of intervals in `A` and `B`, and a priority queue of events.

The tree of intervals need to support a logarithmic "find and return interval containing `i` if it exists".  It also needs to support a logarithmic "add `i` to tree, extending/merging intervals as appropriate, and return new interval".  And likewise a logarithmic "remove `i` from tree, shortening, splitting, or deleting its interval as appropriate".

Events can be of the form "remove `B[i]`" or "add `A[i]`".  The priority queue is sorted first by the size of the element added/subtracted, and then by putting `B` before `A`.  (So we do not elements of size `x` to `A` until all of the elements of size `x` are removed from `B`.)

With that in mind, here is pseudocode for how to do it.

```
Put all possible events in the priority queue
Initialize an empty tree of intervals A_tree
Initialize a tree of intervals B_tree containing the entire range
Initialize max interval to (0, -1) (length 0)

For each event (type, i) in queue:
    if event.type = A:
        new_interval = A_tree.add(event.i)
        
        if event.i in B_tree:
            Intersect event.i's A_tree interval with event.i's B_tree interval
            if intersection is longer than max_interval:
                update to new and better max_interval

    else:
        if event.i in A_tree:
            Intersect event.i's A_tree interval with event.i's B_tree interval
            if intersection is longer than max_interval:
                update to new and better max_interval

        B_tree.remove(event.i)
```

Processing any event is `O(log(n)`. There are `2n = O(n)` events. So overall time is `O(n log(n))`.